# How to export PDF binary from Hbase Shell?

Tags: shell, hbase

I'm using something like this:

```
echo "get 'myfiles', '3ifecre1Row', {COLUMN=>'file:data', FILTER=>'ValueFilter(=,\'binaryprefix:%\')'}" | hbase shell | grep "^ " > testfile.pdf
```

The PDF starts with %PDF-1.6

I don't know why but it won't come out correctly. It says corrupted. I also tried without valueFilter.

Each time it gets the PDF when you "vi" the file it says:

`file:data timestamp=391824122, value='%PDF-1.6.......\x06\x01\x05\x44.......`.

Answer (score 0):

HBase shell is probably not the right solution as it displays binary values as a list of hexadecimal codes. I would use HBASE REST

```
curl -s http://hbase-rest:8080/myfiles/3ifecre1Row/file:data -o testfile.pdf
```

Replace hbase-rest:8080 by your site settings.